# Types of Declaring variables in C++

Tags: c++

If I have a structure called student 
so what's the difference between these

```
Student& refFriend;
Student* ptrFriend;
Student valFriend;
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: srsly... every(!) (good) c++ book or tutorial would cover this..

Comment: no it's n't a homework for sure 
I ask for what's the effect of every one of these in RAM 
and how the size they need in RAM 
thank You for all answers .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First one is a reference type, you need to initialize it with an instance of `Student`. Once it refers to an instance, you cannot change it to refer to another instance. Its fixed.
- Second one is a pointer to `Student` object. You can change the pointer to point to another `Student` object, and you can do this as many times as you want. If you use `new` to create a pointer to `Student` object,  you must have to use `delete` to deallocate the memory once you're done with the object, or else your program would be leaking memory.
- Third one is an automatic object. The object will get destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extremely basic question. I would suggest finding an introductory tutorial on C++ and reading about variables, pointers (Student*), and references (Student&).

Answer (score 2):

**Student& refFriend;**

This is called a reference to object `Student`.

**Student* ptrFriend;**

This is called a pointer to an object `Student`.

**Student valFriend;**

This is declaring object `Student` with variable name `valFriend`. It is sometimes called a stack object.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:
[What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

For an in depth look at the differences between pointers and references.

Answer (score 0):

```
Student& refFriend; //reference pointer to Student. constant pointer, assigned only once
Student* ptrFriend; //pointer to Student. this is a dynamic pointer. can be reasigned
Student valFriend;  //instance of the Student class
```